# Which norm should I use when mixing a vector and matrix?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, matrix-equations, matrix-norms

Consider a vector $y\in \mathbb{R}^n$, which is defined by
$$
y = Wx
$$
where $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $W\in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$. I want to induce the following inequality:
$$
\|y\|_2\leq \|W\|\|x\|_2
$$
where $\|\cdot\|_2$ is the $2$-norm. In this case, I thought that we should use the spectral norm for $\|W\|$, which is the largest singular value of $W$ because it is the corresponding matrix norm induced by the vector $2$-Euclidean norm.

My question is that I can safely replace the spectrom norm for $W$ with the Frobenius norm? That is, does the following inequality make sense?
$$
\|y\|_2\leq \|W\|_F\|x\|_2
$$
It seems that the above inequality is used in the paper I am reading.

Comment: The induced norm on operators: $\|W\|=\sup_{x\neq0}\frac{\|Wx\|_2}{\|x\|_2}$.

Comment: A minor correction. The $l_{2}$ norm should be the 2-Euclidean norm! $l_{2}$ is an infinite dimensional space, whereas you are working in  $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. I know that this term is also used but I think it only confuses people!

Comment: @AnthonySaint-Criq Thank you for your comment. The definition you write is equivalent to the largest singular value of $W$.

Comment: @GeorgeTsoutsinos Thanks for your correction!

Answer (score 1):

You can immediately prove that $\lVert Wx\rVert_2\le \lVert W\rVert_F \lVert x\rVert_2$ by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality in the form
$$
(\sum_j a_jb_j )^2 \le \sum_{j_1}a_{j_1}^2 \sum_{j_2}b_{j_2}^2.$$
Indeed,
$$
\lVert Wx\rVert_2^2=\sum_i (\sum_j W_{i{\,}j}x_j)^2 \le \sum_i \sum_{j_1} W_{i{\,}j_1}^2\sum_{j_2} x_{j_2}^2 =\lVert W\rVert_F^2\lVert x\rVert_2^2.$$